# Keeping R Markdown syntax highlighting when printing

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, rstudio

I'm afraid the response will be: "Markdown is meant to be simple and it doesn't do that", but it (almost) never hurts to ask.

When writing an R Markdown document I can view the HTML file in a browser and it looks great.  When I try to print it, either on paper or as PDF, the color in the figures is printed but not the syntax highlighting.  Is there a way to maintain syntax highlighting when printing?

Example:

````
Minimal Example
=====

This text looks great in the file and the plot prints in color, but see commented code     below.

```{r}
# this commented line will be green in the HTML file, but will be black when I print it
z <- cor(mtcars) 
require(lattice) # 'require' will be blue in the HTML file, but will be black when I print it
levelplot(z)
```
````

I push the "Knit HTML" button in RStudio and open the HTML in Chrome or Safari and there are no problems.  If I print from the HTML from the browser all the syntax highlighting is lost.

Comment: Can you give a minimal reproducible example of your workflow?

Comment: What kind of R markdown? knitr?

Comment: Is there another way to use R Markdown? Please elaborate.

Comment: There are always many ways to skin a cat. For r markdown you could also use [pander](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander)

Comment: The use of the `knit2HTML` button is critical here. The issue is the way `markdown::markdowntoHTML` highlights

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After doing your 'Knit' to your original example.Rmd you will have an example.md in your working path, then use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)...

```
# for pdf (you need to have latex installed)
system( "pandoc example.md -o example.pdf")

# for syntax-highlight persistant html
system("pandoc example.md -o example.html -s -S")
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I also found is to knit to HTML, preview the html file in the browser, and then highlight everything and paste it into a MS Word document. From there you can export to PDF or print. It unfortunately does not copy all of the images to the Word document. But if all you need is the syntax highlighting, and not too worried about images or plots, then this solution is fairly straight forward. It actually copies the boxes of code a little better than the pandoc solution, but with the drawback of no images.